# Mvc doesnt validate input type file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I am using strongly type view model for my view , Validation works for all the text fields but it doesnt work for fileupload , below is the code:

```
        <div class="bg-content-inner">
            <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Track", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                  { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please Correct the errors and try again")%>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px;">



        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>
        </td>

                        <td colspan="2">
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:300px;" })%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name,"Circuit Name Required") %>
        </div>

         </td>
                    </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                           Main Image
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" style="color:White" />
                            <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageLarge,"Required") %>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Detail Image
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" style="color:White" />
                            <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageSmall,"Required") %>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the validation message is looking for ImageLarge and ImageSmall to validate against.
If you change the name and id attributes to match the model image names does it work? e.g
    name="ImageLarge" id="ImageLarge"

Comment: Well if i cant change the name  to imagelarge as I am using it on the backhand in create controller like : foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)....

Comment: This might help with jQuery, there is also a plain JavaScript version in the link above: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222502/jquery-input-type-file-image-filetype-validation-options

Answer (score 4):

If you are using unobtrusive validation, the ***HtmlHelpers*** will insert some ***data-XXXX*** attributes to enable client-side validation... since MVC does not have a HtmlHelper for ***INPUT[FILE]*** and you have to ***manually*** insert the INPUT element... you can also add the ***data-XXXX*** attributes yourself... them and the client-side validation will work (well... at least in FF and Chrome... I have not tested it in others)... so...

replace:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file2" style="color:White" />
```

with:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file2" style="color:White" data-val="true" data-val-required="File is required" />
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This works, and you can pull the message from the model attribute using the extensions method described in the accepted answer here (last update)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970184/accessing-attributes-from-custom-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-4-razor

Comment: This is so simple and so powerful! It extends the validation to so much more than just the input controls part of the model. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You can't client-side validate an `<input type="file" />`; it must be POSTed to the server and the upload examined, there just isn't a way around this.

Comment: You mean there is no way in mvc i can validate html file upload , if one has selected the file or not

Comment: No, at least not with the built-in validation. Could perhaps do some javascript tricks to check manually.

Comment: Have you got any tutorials or examples on how to acheive that using jquery

Answer (score 0):

May be [AjaxSubmit](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/03/image-preview-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) helps you.