# Make sure an input field has a value before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make sure that the input has value before submit but when I use "" or 'null', it, null will not disable it and "" will keep it disabled no matter what.
Here is my code:

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    $("#container").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $("#container").fadeOut();
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;

});
if (document.getElementById("m").value === null) {
  document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;
} else if (document.getElementById("m").value !== null) {
  document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
} else {
  $(function() {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function() {
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $("#m").val("");
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));

    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<div id="msgs">
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
</div>
<form action="">
  <div id="container">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button id="send">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

thanks!

Comment: just add a `required` in input tag!

Comment: `<input type="text" required />`

Comment: You can also try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125255/how-i-know-if-my-input-type-file-has-content-selected

Comment: You can also try it this way [Refer to this Post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279628/checking-the-form-field-values-before-submitting-that-page)

Comment: In case you are looking for customised validations on your page Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript
This enables you to check for all the falsey values instead of a lengthy `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the new `required` attribute in HTML5:

```
<input id="m" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute

This answer is just like an alternative technique for form data validation, cuz we have many ways to implement form data validation, from basic to advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use length of value

```
if (document.getElementById("m").value.length>0) concole.log('input not empty');
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not Jquery expert and I can't understand why would you use it anyway but your problem is you don't have event listener to the elements you changing. It means - Javascript remember the values you had in your elements on run time, later when you change it , it cant read the new values without proper listener. Therefor , `""` will keep it disabled. read https://api.jquery.com/change/ about the `change` listener of Jquery

Answer (score 1):

I don't think required is a good way since I can easily disable it by just taking a look at the html code.

So what you should do instead is add an event listener. Each time your user types something you check if the `input` is empty or not. If it is you disable the button, if it isn't you activate the button.

And also: Always check in the backend aswell!!!

Answer (score 1):

please use if (document.getElementById("m").value == '')  instead of yours

```
 <div id="msgs">
                    <ul id="messages"></ul>
                </div>
                <form action="">
                    <div id="container">
                        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button id="send">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
            <script>

                var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
                    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
                        $("#container").fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $("#container").fadeOut();
                    }
                    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;

                });
    runcheck();  
    $("#m").keyup(function(){
    runcheck();
    });





    function runcheck(){
    if (document.getElementById("m").value == '') {
                    document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("m").value != null) {
                    document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
                }  else {
                    $(function () {
                        var socket = io();
                        $('form').submit(function () {
                            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                            $("#m").val("");
                            return false;
                        });
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
                    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));

                });

                    });
                }
    }


            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

In your example code, I can see several problems.

1. It does not seem as if you have a listener for changes on the imput

   - you’ll need to add an event listener on your html element to know if there is any change. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener then based on the event you get you can check for the value using `event.target.value`.
2. Your value checking is wrong

   - You can check if fields have values by doing just `if(document.getElementById("m").value)` no need for `=== null`.

## Solution

Just use the `required` attribute on your html element. That will add basic html form validation and prevent submission when the input is empty. As long as it is in a form element. See [MDN Docs on required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute) for more info.

```
<input id="m" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

Then to toggle the disabled status you could check for the validity in JavaScript. Here is an untested pseudocode:

```
const sendButton = document.querySelector('#send');  // grab the button
const mInput = document.querySelector('#m');  // grab the input

sendButton.disabled = true;  // disable it by default

mInput.addEventListener('change', event => {  // as soon as the input value changes
  sendButton.disabled = !event.target.checkValidity();  // set the disabled state based on the validity of the input field (event.target is the input field) (the little exclamation mark before the validity check means "not". !true === false and !false === true
});
```

Note that in most browsers the `change` listener only triggers when the focus changed to another element. So you might want to check on `keyup` or something like that. Check out the events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener (on the left side menu under "events")

*PS: Generally. Looking at your code. I would advise taking some absolute beginner courses on web development, in particular, html+css+javascript. I guess codecademy is a good place to start.*

Answer (score 0):

required is not a good solution because you can just turn it of in browser console
I recommend:

`if (document.getElementById("m").value == '') {
   //code here...
}`

You can check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript) for more info

I hope this will help you

Comment: You can also turn Javascript off :)

Comment: @DavidLavender how can you turn off javascript for every user?